# why i have this error overloading an operator?

Tags: c++

i want to define an operator for sort a vector of objects "esame" but i have this error:

> /*    esame.cpp:46:6: error: prototype for 'bool
>   esame::operator<(esame&) const' does not match any in class 'esame'
>        bool esame::operator<(esame &exam) const 
>             ^~~~~
>       In file included from esame.cpp:1:0:*/
>       esame.h:20:10: error: candidate is: bool esame::operator<(const esame&) const

```
     bool operator<(const esame &) const

    //this is the declaration on the header file:

    bool operator<(const esame &) const;





    //this is implementation on the cpp file:

    bool esame::operator<(esame &exam) const
    {
        if (this->getNome() < exam.getNome()){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Not related to the error, but the result of `this->getNome() < exam.getNome()` is already a `bool`. You don't need the `if`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signatures are different. Add `const` to `esame &exam` in the implementation.